# Json data using kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, moshi

I am currently working on an app and I would like to have a JSON extraction to a class but it's a little more difficult that just matching field. I am using Moshi for the JSON management.

Below is the JSON I have :

```
{
  "common" :{
    "source_url": "xxxx",
    "target_url": "yyy
  },
  "specific":{
    "A":{
      "setting": "ccc",
    },
    "B":{
      "setting": "ddd",
    }
  }
}
```

The goal for me is to get an object based on a data class which look like this:

```
data class config(
    val sourceUrl: String,
    val targetUrl: String,
    val setting: String
)
```

What I have started is to first create the different data class to allow me to manipulate the data before getting the above class object.

--GeneralConfig.kt

```
data class GeneralConfig(
    val common: CommonConfig,
    val specific: Specific
)
```

-- CommonConfig.kt

```
data class CommonConfig(
    @Json(val name = "source_url") sourceUrl: String,
    @Json(val name = "target_url") val targetUrl: String
)
```

-- SpecificConfig.kt

```
data class SpecificConfig(
    setting: String,
)
```

I have 2 main questions:

- How can I access the "specific" "A/B" data and get an object class `SpecificConfig`. Can I in my `generalConfig` data class directly extract one field from `specific` and select `A` or `B` by passing an argument
- Is it possible to avoid creating multiple data class to get my final class object `config`

The purpose is to have a json containing a common data and specific data. I need to build a final data class which a merge from the common data and one of the specific data.

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Your class structure needs to match with your JSON structure. Your JSON "specific" object doesn't contain a single field named "setting". It contains **two** fields named A and B. And both of these fields are objects with a field named setting. So your Kotlin class structure needs to match that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this
1. Modify your

```
data class SpecificConfig(
    setting: String,
)
```

To

```
data class SpecificConfig(
@Json(val name = "A") val a : JsonObject,
    @Json(val name = "B") val b: JsonObject
)
```

Second: Create another 2 classes i.e

```
data class AConfig(
    setting: String,
)

data class BConfig(
    setting: String,
)
```

Third: Modify

```
data class config(
    val sourceUrl: String,
    val targetUrl: String,
    val setting: String
)
```

To

```
data class config(
    val sourceUrl: String,
    val targetUrl: String,
    val setting: String,
    val a: JsonObject,
    val b: JsonObject
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to create classes for every request and to not parse them manually

```
data class GeneralConfig(
        @SerializedName("common") val common: CommonConfig,
        @SerializedName("specific") val specific: Specific
                        )

data class CommonConfig(
        @SerializedName("source_url") val sourceUrl: String,
        @SerializedName("target_url") val targetUrl: String
                 )

data class Specific(
        @SerializedName("A") val a: SpecificSettings,
        @SerializedName("B") val b: SpecificSettings
                 )

data class SpecificSettings(
        @SerializedName("setting") val setting: String
                 )
```

Comment: ok thanks. I was trying to make a smarter code to avoid having a class for `Specific` by being able to pass A or B as an argument to get the "setting" field inside. A and B are used as example but you can have C, D,.... the goal is to have a json which can support more setting and avoid updating the code each time. I just had to pass the params A or B